# Не могу найти форму в DELPHI

Tags: delphi

Скрин:

[image]

Мне нужно его название, чтоб я мог его найти в панели форм.

Comment: @Jek, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TComboBox

Comment: @hovadur Спасибо